# Google Map API can't create project

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have never create a google project, and when I try to get a key of google map api, it says
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUjJM.jpg)

Comment: Try again. and is there any error exception shown?

Answer (score 1):

Please click on the 'GET A KEY' tab and follow the process. Pick a new name for your project and create a key.

Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key